Is there control over where lci zero dimensional subschemes can be?
Let $X$ be a smooth algebraic variety. Consider the collection $\mathfrak{Z}$ of all lci dimension zero subschemes of $X$. Then is it ever possible that $\cup_{Z\in \mathfrak{Z}} Z$ is contained in a proper subvariety of $X$?
Here is why I hope this is an interesting question.
My impression is that this is likely false. I saw a post here where it is claimed that if $Z$ is any zero dimensional subscheme, then there exists a zero dimensional subscheme $Z'$ which is lci and $Z\subseteq Z'$. I don't see why this needs to be true since being lci is a local condition. I guess maybe it is to allow one to thicken the points of $Z$. Also the question is in the case of arithmetically gorenstein subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^n$. Here, I am allowing $X$ to be any smooth quasiprojective variety.
So in fact, I am betting that $\cup_{Z\in \mathfrak{Z}} Z$ is probably Zariski dense in $X$. But I've got no idea how to prove this at the moment.

Any point of a smooth variety is an lci subscheme, and the union of all points of $X$ is already the whole $X$.
Edit. If $X$ is not smooth but Cohen--Macaulay, for each point $x \in X$ there is an lci subscheme $Z_x \subset X$ supported at $x$. Indeed, just choose a regular sequence in the maximal ideal of $x$ of the length equal to the dimension of $X$ and use it to define $Z_x$.

Oops I was being dumb. I am curious if such a statement is also true if I don't assume smooth? I guess this follows from just using Zariski denseness of the nonsingular locus?

I added an explanation about the CM case.
